# [Django Rest Framework]: How to additional phone_number field on Registration page?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I successfully created apis which can generate token on user login and register, also have a api page where i can display all the registered users (admin privileges required). But im not able to add a additional field like phone number on my register page.

I need a phone number field as well on the registration page. Currently it has firstName, lastName, email and password.

#### Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_profile')
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

#### Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from .models import Profile


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    firstName = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True) 
    lastName = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'firstName', 'lastName']

    def get_firstName(self, obj):
        firstName = obj.first_name
        return firstName

    def get_lastName(self, obj):
        lastName = obj.last_name
        return lastName


class UserSerializerWithToken(UserSerializer):
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'token']

    def get_token(self, obj):
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(obj)
        return str(token.access_token)
```

#### Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser
from .serializers import ProfileSerializer, UserSerializer, UserSerializerWithToken
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from rest_framework import status


class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)

        serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(self.user).data
        for k, v in serializer.items():
            data[k] = v

        return data


class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer


@api_view(['POST'])
def registerUser(request):
    data = request.data

    try:
        user = User.objects.create(
            first_name=data['firstName'],
            last_name=data['lastName'],
            username=data['email'],
            email=data['email'],
            password=make_password(data['password']))


        serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(user, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    except:
        message = {'detail': 'User with this email already exists'}
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def getUserProfile(request):
    user = request.user
    serializer = UserSerializer(user, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def getUsers(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a custom User model and add the phone_number field, or simply add it to the Profile model. The Django docs recommend you define a custom user model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Comment: Thanks, i wil try it and if it works i will let you know.